# How to apply conditional formatting to specific item in list which is created through Array

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Java and android development.

I have an ListView. What I would like to do is apply conditional formatting (different background) to a specific row.

```
String[] cars = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda","Toyota","VW"};

listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.routelistview);
final ArrayList<String>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i< cars.length; i++){
    arrayList.add(cars[i]);
 }

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
System.out.println("test test test test test");

if (Arrays.asList(listView).contains("Mazda")){
   listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9fe7ff"));
 }

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(RouteSelection.this, "Clicked Item:"+i+ " "+arrayList.get(i).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
});
```

What I want to do is add a different colour background if the item is "**Ford**"

I tried doing it with this code but this did not work.

```
if (Arrays.asList(listView).contains("Mazda")){
   listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9fe7ff"));
 }
```

My question is how to check if certain item = "<>" in arrayAdapter and apply conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a custom Adapter to do this, and example of custom adapter with conditional formatting of a listview is shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878344/2373819